# How to use CanDeactivate guard when leave application (NOT component)

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

In my application, the user can be tested, see the test results. And this is all without registration (such as login-password). But if he wants to leave the application, I want to offer him to register, otherwise his data will not be saved.
I do not want to offer to register when leaving a certain component, only if he wants to leave the application.
I am new to angular. Perhaps for this problem there is another solution in angular, not related to CanDeactivate guard.

UPDATE:

thanks to Sergey Mell, for the angular did as follows:

```
export abstract class DeactivationGuarded {
 abstract canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
 unloadNotification($event: any) {
  if (!this.canDeactivate()) {
   $event.returnValue = true;
  }
 }
}
```

And then extends root component from DeactivationGuarded.

But it does not work for 'onpagehide'.

Comment: What means `leave the application`? You can't block user from closing page unless using standard `confirm` dialog

Comment: I don't want to block user from closing page. I just want to offer him a confirmation dialog (using CanDeactivate guard or something else) when he want to close page .

Comment: I want the user freely navigate the application components, but at the moment when he closes the application, he will be offered a confirmation.

Comment: I think your question is if there's a place to don't put `canDeactivate` on every route, the answer is: No, but you can put it on you main component, so it's the same as your entire application

Comment: Thank you for answer. That's exactly what i did. The only problem is that when the user leaves the main page (index.html), the warning does not show, since it is higher than the main component.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your solution should look smth like this

```
function myConfirmation() {
    if (user.isRegistered) {
       return;
    }
    // Open your fancy registration dialog here;
    return 'Please, register. Otherwise your data will not be saved';
}

window.onbeforeunload = myConfirmation;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's helped, but not work for onpagehide.